# An error occurred (AuthFailure) AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials: ClientError from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image: Click here to see screenshot of Error Log]

I am trying to run the below command from lambda function but I keep getting the error AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials. I am very sure that the credentials are correct because the access credentials are the set of credentials I use in my local AWS CLI. Does anyone have any idea?

```
 ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=str(REGION_NAME), aws_access_key_id=str(ACCESS_KEY), aws_secret_access_key=str(SECRET_KEY))
```

Comment: Best practice is use IAM role over hard coded credential as already said. But i wonder why your code doesn't work. because as far as I know, when you pass credential to the boto directly in code, it should take precedence  over IAM role.  my suspission is that the code is not getting the credential from the variables. try to log the credential to see if the code is receiving the credential.

Comment: does it mean that once I attach example ec2 full access permission to a role and attach this role to my lambda, I can call boto3.client without passing in the credentials?

Comment: Yes. you can just remove both access key and secret key parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using lambda function, its permissions should be provided using [AWS Lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html):

> An AWS Lambda function's execution role **grants it permission to access AWS services and resources**. You provide this role when you create a function, and Lambda assumes the role when your function is invoked.

I know it does not answer directly to your question, but this is **good practice** and you should not hard code any IAM credentials in your lambda function or its environmental variables.